# Function to handle value of form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to write a small function that "fakes" the behavior of the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute a bit. I know that there are already plugins out there that do this, but I want to write it myself because I really want to get better at jQuery.

So far, this is what should happen I believe. If you spot any unnecessary stuff please tell me.

1. On function call, it searches the DOM for a given form and adds a CSS class to any input fields/textareas, leaving out `input[type="submit"]` and `<button>`.
2. If there is a value, that value is placed in an array or object, together with the input's/textarea's ID, like `#myInputID => initial value`.
3. On focus, the CSS class is removed and it is checked if the current value exists inside the array/object. If the value is found, it is removed so that the input/textarea is empty. If it is not found, nothing happens and the value stays.
4. On blur it is checked if the field is empty or if the current value is found in the array/object. If it is found or the input's/textarea's value is empty, the inital value from the object/array is placed again, together with re-adding the CSS class. If value is not found in the array or object, the value stays and the CSS class won't be re-added.

In code that could look like this:

```
function placeholder( element ) {
  var values = [];
  console.log( values );

    $( element ).find( ":input" ).each( function() {
      var $this = $( this );

      // adding CSS class
      $this.addClass( "light" );

      if( $this.val() ){
        // adding value to array
        // the key is missing, maybe add an id to the elements?
        values.push( $this.val() );
      }

      $this.focus( function(){
        // remove CSS class
        $this.removeClass( "light" );

        // if value is in array  
        var i = $.inArray( $this.val() , values );
        if( i != -1 ) {
          $this.val( "" );
        }
      })// focus

      $this.blur(function(){
        // setting value to inital value if needed
        // add CSS class
        var i = $.inArray( $this.val() , values );
        if( i == -1 ) {
          $this.val( "initalValue" );
          $this.addClass( "light" );
        }
      })// blur

    }) // each
} // function

placeholder( "form" );
```

Of course it is not finished and there are still several issues (it isn't even working...), but I can't work it out by myself. These are my main problems:

- Should I use an array or an object (hashmap?) for saving the key => value pairs? I found different opinions on this, even here on SO. And how do I compare the values? How do I push values in such an array/object?
- At some point it would be a good idea to cache `$this.val()`. Whats the best place to do this?
- Any major performance issues with the code?
- When the blur event is triggered, the value needs to be reseted to it's initial value if the user hasn't entered anything. This isn't working because I don't have any key in my array to identify the elements.

Here is a Fiddle for quick testing: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZgvL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as complicated as you're making it...

**jQuery**:

```
$('#myform').
on('focus', '.autoclear', function () {
    if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
        this.value = '';
    }
    $(this).removeClass('blur').addClass('focus');
}).
on('blur', '.autoclear', function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
    $(this).removeClass('focus').addClass('blur');
});
```

**HTML**:

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/L2pfW/**

```
<input type="text" name="field" value="name" class="autoclear" />
```

Comment: Problem is, the user is unable to enter the text 'name' and then edit it.  You'd better pick placeholder text that has no chance of conflicting with valid input.  Well, there's that and the fact that there's already a standard attribute for placeholder text...and you're basically just abusing another attribute to do its job.

Comment: If you're going to add attributes to DOM elements, use the `data` prefix. Not to mention that your code has a bug when the user types in a value that equals the default value

Comment: @cHao, yes, the above is a _generic_ example.  If somebody's address or phone number is simply "address" or "phone", then you've obviously got a goofball messing with your form and it wouldn't pass validation anyway.

Comment: @kinso, if the entered value equals the default value, then in most normal use cases it would also fail validation.

Comment: Quote @kinsho: _"If you're going to add attributes to DOM elements, use the data prefix."_ ~ I did not "add" anything...  `type`, `name`, `value` and `class` are all existing and valid `attributes`.

Comment: @cHao, the standard placeholder attribute is HTML5 and the whole point of the OP's question is to "fake" the HTML5 behavior, presumably without HTML5.  See the OP's very first sentence.

Comment: @Sparky: The whole point of the question was to get placeholder text.  That already works in HTML 5, and there are attributes and everything defined for it.  The less hideous course of action would be to set the HTML5-standard attribute and add code to fake the placeholder *if the browser doesn't natively support it*.  Cause it won't be long til they all do, and if you're just shimming HTML5 support, you can remove the placeholder-faking code entirely.

Comment: @cHao, I agree with you but that doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking for.  Please post an answer since you already seem to know how this can be done better.

Comment: @Sparky: My answer would basically involve a rewrite.  :P  That seems to defeat the OP's goals of doing it himself.  If you care, though... http://jsfiddle.net/bfmFq/3/

Comment: @cHao, I appreciate that, but if he really wants to do it himself, why did he post the question?  Maybe it needs to be closed.  After all, we're here to answer specific programming questions, not have a subjective discussion with the OP giving him opinions and tips.

Answer (score 1):

For saving key-value pairs, use an object that you access like an associative array. The key should be something unique to the input field containing the value (like its ID, perhaps). So taking from your following example....

```
if( $this.val() ){
     // adding value to array
     values[$this.attr('id')] = $this.val();
}
```

Retrieving any value becomes straightforward at this point: just use the ID of the element. You also take away any need to search the entire values array to look for a value now that you can search by ID. So performance would also be improved there.